# How to remove a tent pole cord from a pole tip?

Tags: tents, diy, maintenance

We have lots of tent pole segments and I'd like to repair one of our poles but the cord is stuck on the inside of the tip. I had to just cut the cord just so I can work with the tip alone.

Any tips on how to remove the cord from the tip? The tip is something like this: [image: tips]

The knot of the cord passes through the thing and you can see the bulb from the outside of the narrow end.

Maybe there is an easier and more elegant solution than simply hammering a nail through.

Answer (score 4):

Typically these are not meant to be messed with. Even if you could get to the knot I'd imagine you would struggle to get it un-done. Basically, in my experience, cutting it is often the best/only solution. Just try and save as much cord as you can.

FYI tent pole repair companies will often sell extra cord should you need it.